# Angular2 router (@angular/router), how to set default route?

Tags: angular

How can I set a default route in my @Routes route metadata collection?  If you use the angular2 router from @angular/router-deprecated you define the routes in @routeConfig object, which is a collection of route objects, but these route objects have more attributes on them.  For instance they have 'name' and 'useAsDefualt' attributes whereas the routes defined out of @angular/router do not.  I would like to write my new app using the new router, but how do i use the new router and set a default route?

This is my main app component which defines my routes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ConfigManagerComponent } from './configManager/configManager.component';
import { ApplicationMgmtComponent } from './applicationMgmt/applicationMgmt.component';
import { MergeComponent } from './merge/merge.component';

import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-container',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@Routes([

        { path: '/Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: '/ConfigManager', component: ConfigManagerComponent },
        { path: '/Merge', component: MergeComponent },
        { path: '/ApplicationManagement', component: ApplicationMgmtComponent }
])

export class AppComponent { }
```

The route definitions seem to be working fine, when I click on anchor tags like this one:

```
<li class="nav hidden-xs"><a [routerLink]="['./Dashboard']">Dashboard</a>/li>
```

It transitions to the associated route.  My only issue is that when my app loads it doesn't have a route active.  How do i define a default route that is active when my app bootstraps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 188, accepted):

**V2.0.0 and later**

See also see https://angular.io/guide/router#the-default-route-to-heroes

```ts
RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/detail', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'detail', component: HeroDetailComponent }
    ] 
  }
];
```

There is also the catch-all route

```ts
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

which redirects "invalid" urls.

**V3-alpha (vladivostok)**

Use path `/` and `redirectTo`

```ts
RouterConfig = [
  { path: '/', redirectTo: 'heroes', terminal: true },
  { path: 'heroes', component: HeroComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '/', redirectTo: 'detail', terminal: true },
      { path: 'detail', component: HeroDetailComponent }
    ] 
  }
];
```

**RC.1 @angular/router**

The RC router doesn't yet support `useAsDefault`. As a workaround you can navigate explicitely.

In the root component

```ts
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(router:Router) {
    router.navigate(['/Merge']);
  }
}
```

for other components

```ts
export class OtherComponent {
  constructor(private router:Router) {}

  routerOnActivate(curr: RouteSegment, prev?: RouteSegment, currTree?: RouteTree, prevTree?: RouteTree) : void {
    this.router.navigate(['SomeRoute'], curr);
  }
}
```

Comment: When i try to use Rotuer in the constructor Typescript complains about not finding "Router".  Do i need to import this?

Comment: You need to import any type used in your file. If you add `Router` as type to any variable or parameter, you need to import it.

Comment: Yeah right after I posted I tried this:
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes, Router } from '@angular/router';
seems to work now, thanks!

Comment: You are missing a closing curly bracket on this line:

{ path: '', redirectTo: '/heroes', pathMatch: 'full',

I cannot add it because edits must be at least 6 characters, please add it

Comment: What if wanna redirect to a path where an id is needed as the default path?

Comment: Can you please create a new question with more details?

Comment: @Ced I think it should work. You can also use `this.router.navigateByUrl("/");`. Did you run into an issue with your code example?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it was an error on my side. When there is an hash fragment  and  one calls `window.location.hash = '' ` prior navigation, it won't navigate at all (DefaultStrategy).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What's `terminal: true` do in your code ?

Comment: It's from an old version. It means there are no child routes - not relevant anymore. See https://angular.io/guide/router#the-default-route-to-heroes for default routes

Answer (score 19):

You set path of route is ''.
Example for DashboardComponent is load first.

```
@Routes([
        { path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: '/ConfigManager', component: ConfigManagerComponent },
        { path: '/Merge', component: MergeComponent },
        { path: '/ApplicationManagement', component: ApplicationMgmtComponent }
])
```

Hope it help you.

Comment: notice that, on load, app will navigate to `DashboardComponent` but `URL` will be empty instead of `/dashboard`

Comment: Thank you for supplying this approach.  The only thing im hesitant about is that the route isn't explicitly referenced in the url.  I would like to maintain the /Dashboard suffix on the url.  But otherwise this would work really well.

Answer (score 11):

In Angular 2+, you can set route to default page by adding this route to your route module. In this case login is my target route for the default page.

```
{path:'',redirectTo:'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
```

Answer (score 6):

according to documentation you should just

```
{ path: '**', component: DefaultLayoutComponent }
```

on your app-routing.module.ts
source: https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: quick note, the order in which the path is set is important.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose you want to load **RegistrationComponent** on load and then **ConfirmationComponent** on some event click on **RegistrationComponent**.

So in `appModule.ts`, you can write like this.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { 
        path: '', 
        redirectTo: 'registration', 
        pathMatch: 'full'
       },
       { 
        path: 'registration', 
        component: RegistrationComponent
       },
      {
        path : 'confirmation',
        component: ConfirmationComponent
      }
    ])
```

OR

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
       { 
        path: '', 
        component: RegistrationComponent
       },
      {
        path : 'confirmation',
        component: ConfirmationComponent
      }
    ])
```

is also fine.
Choose whatever you like.

Answer (score 3):

The path should be left blank to make it default component.

```
{ path: '', component: DashboardComponent },
```

Comment: Right, if you want to redirect to app component, use { path: ' ', component: AppComponent},

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue apply all possible solution but finally this solve my problem

```
export class AppRoutingModule {
constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.errorHandler = (error: any) => {
        this.router.navigate(['404']); // or redirect to default route
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3):

I just faced the same issue, I managed to make it work on my machine, however the change I did is not the same way it is mentioned in the documentation so it could be an issue of angular version routing module, mine is Angular 7

It only worked when I changed the lazy module main route entry path with same path as configured at the app-routes.ts

```
routes = [{path:'', redirectTo: '\home\default', pathMatch: 'full'},
           {path: '', 
           children: [{
             path:'home',
             loadChildren :'lazy module path'      
           }]

         }];

 routes configured at HomeModule
 const routes = [{path: 'home', redirectTo: 'default', pathMatch: 'full'},
             {path: 'default', component: MyPageComponent},
            ]

 instead of 
 const routes = [{path: '', redirectTo: 'default', pathMatch: 'full'},
                   {path: 'default', component: MyPageComponent},
                ]
```

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of angular 2 you can't use '/' on a path or give a name to your route.
What you can do is create a route file like "app.routes.ts" and import your components, make sure of the path when importing.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ConfigManagerComponent } from './configManager/configManager.component';
import { ApplicationMgmtComponent } from './applicationMgmt/applicationMgmt.component';
import { MergeComponent } from './merge/merge.component';`
```

Add:

```
import {RouterConfig, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
```

Then your routes:

```
const routes:RouterConfig = [      
    { path: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'ConfigManager', component: ConfigManagerComponent },
    { path: 'Merge', component: MergeComponent },
    { path: 'ApplicationManagement', component: ApplicationMgmtComponent }
 ];
```

Then export:

```
export  const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)]
```

In your main.ts import `APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS` and add bootstrap the router providers to the main.ts like this:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent,[APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

Finally, your link will look like this:

```
li class="nav hidden-xs"><a [routerLink]="['./Dashboard']" routerLinkActive="active">Dashboard</a>/li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only you need to add other parameter in your route, the parameter is useAsDefault:true. For example, if you want the DashboardComponent as default you need to do this:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent , useAsDefault:true},
    .
    .
    .
    ])
```

I recomend you to add names to your routes.

```
{ path: '/Dashboard',name:'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent , useAsDefault:true}
```