# Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My component shows up but i get an error message when the page is loaded. I can't seem to solve the error message at all after looking at a bunch of resources.

##### Error

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: 'index.html'. Available routes: ['/login'].

main.component.ts is in index.html and as soon as the page loads it shows the above error message.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'main-component',
    template: 
      ' <header>
           <h1>Budget Calculator</h1>
           <a id='login' [routerLink]="['/login']">Login</a>
           <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </header> '
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})

@Routes([
    {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent}
])

export class MainComponent {}
```

login.component.ts is routed through the main.component.ts and does show when I click on the link despite the error message. Right now I have it styled to popup over the other elements in main.component but would like it to be the only component that shows on the page. Basically replace main.component in index.html with login.component if this possible instead of doing a whole bunch of styling to display: none.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    template: 
        ' <div id="login-pop-up">
              <h6 class="header_title">Login</h6>
              <div class="login-body">
                   Some fancy login stuff goes here
              </div>
          </div> '
})

export class LoginComponent {}
```

Comment: The FIRST thing to check is that one has a Route specified for the route in question.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- This might be because your server needs to be configured for **HTML5 pushState** like explained in [Angular 2.0 router not working on reloading the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415052/angular-2-0-router-not-working-on-reloading-the-browser)

Also ensure you have a **`<base href="/">`** tag at the beginning of the `<head>` tag or provided by `boostrap(...)` as explained in [Angular 2 router no base href set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535163/angular-2-router-no-base-href-set/34535256#34535256)

- If you don't have a route for `/` you might need to make the app navigate to an initial route imperatively like explained in [Angular2 router (@angular/router), how to set default route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605119/angular2-router-angular-router-how-to-set-default-route)

**Hint**: The `@angular/router` router also is deprecated as `@angular/router-deprecated` and a new router will be shipped again :-/ If you are about to switch to `@angular/router` it's probably better to postpone until the new and hopefully final router is available.

Comment: I will wait for the new router. Do you have an idea on when it will be released?

Comment: No, but I assume it has quite high priority. This caused quite some uproar. A new RC will be shipped soon. Let's wait and see if a new router will be included.

Comment: Could you link to the discussion on the new-non-deprecated-router?

Comment: The new router is part of RC.3. The Router docs at angular.io are already for this new router.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html   Just wanted to post a direct link....

Answer (score 4):

if you have child component and you want to navigate use this way

**router servive**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'enter',
        component: EnterDetailsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'find',
        component: FindDetailsComponent,
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

use navigate([]) method this way

**component constructor**

this is how this._router comes

```
constructor( private _router: Router) {}

this._router.navigate(['/home/find']);
```

Answer (score 1):

When I have had this problem I typically add

```
<base href="./">
```

to the `<head> <base href="./"> </head>` of html file.

Then when importing any files in NG2

```
import { Auth }                 from './auth.service';
```

This is the prefered way to do base per the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html),
[image]

Answer (score 0):

plz make sure `<base href="/">` tag in your head tag and you can use `useAsDefault: true` attr like this :

```
@Routes([
    {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent,useAsDefault: true}
])
```

Comment: There is no `useAsDefault` in `@angular/router` :-/

Comment: As far as I know this is not yet implemented in `@angular/router` and won't be because it will be replaced again. Adding it doesn't cause an error but it doesn't have any effect either. Maybe you're using `@angular/router-deprecated`?

Comment: yse,i use `@angular/router-deprecated` ,and Whats deference between router and router-deprecated ?

Comment: The difference is that both are deprecated ;-). `@angular/router` is an entirely new implementation that was intended to replace `@angular/router-deprecated` but it didn't fully work out neither and they deprecated it as well. `@angular/router` has several issues and missing features. Currently it's better to stay with `@angular/router-deprecated` until the new new new router is shipped and stable enough.

Comment: tnxx for answer ^-^

Answer (score 0):

just add a route for '' the exception will go.

```
{ 
    path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent 
}
```

Comment: should be path: '**'

Comment: * should also work as it will match any path not just the home path

Comment: i tried it, its not working. You have to specify '**'