# Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

When I run this unit test:

```
it('can click profile link in template', () => {
    const landingPageLinkDe = linkDes[0];
    const profileLinkDe = linkDes[1];
    const aboutLinkDe = linkDes[2];
    const findLinkDe = linkDes[3];
    const addLinkDe = linkDes[4];
    const registerLinkDe = linkDes[5];
    const landingPageLinkFull = links[0];
    const profileLinkFull = links[1];
    const aboutLinkFull = links[2];
    const findLinkFull = links[3];
    const addLinkFull = links[4];
    const registerLinkFull = links[5];

    navFixture.detectChanges();
    expect(profileLinkFull.navigatedTo)
        .toBeNull('link should not have navigated yet');
    profileLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
    landingPageLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
    aboutLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
    registerLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
    findLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
    addLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });

    navFixture.detectChanges();
    expect(landingPageLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/');
    expect(profileLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/profile');
    expect(aboutLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/about');
    expect(findLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/find');
    expect(addLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/add');
    expect(registerLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/register');
});
```

I get this error:

> zone.js:388 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'add' ; Zone: ProxyZone ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error:
>   Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'add'(…) Error: Cannot match any
>   routes. URL Segment: 'add'

The test still passes but it would be interesting to know why I'm getting the error. I don't get the error when I use the application as a user would. I've researched the error and it's usually due to not providing a default path in the routes, however I have done that.

**Am I doing something wrong to cause this error?**

navbar.component.spec.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js';

import {
    ComponentFixture,
    TestBed,
    async,
    fakeAsync
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
    BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
    platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
    DebugElement,
    Component,
    ViewChild,
    Pipe,
    PipeTransform,
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA,
    NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
} from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, RouterOutlet, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar.component';
import { RouterLinkStubDirective } from '../../router-stubs';
import { click } from '../../test/utilities.spec';

describe('NavbarComponent', () => {
    let navComponent: NavbarComponent;
    let navFixture: ComponentFixture<NavbarComponent>;
    let linkDes: any;
    let links: any;
    let landingPageLink: any;
    let profileLink: any;
    let aboutLink: any;
    let findLink: any;
    let addLink: any;
    let registerLink: any;

    beforeAll(() => {
        TestBed.resetTestEnvironment();
        TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
            platformBrowserDynamicTesting());
    });

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                NavbarComponent,
                RouterLinkStubDirective
            ],
            imports: [RouterTestingModule],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        navFixture = TestBed.createComponent(NavbarComponent);
        navComponent = navFixture.componentInstance;
        navFixture.detectChanges();
        linkDes = navFixture.debugElement
            .queryAll(By.directive(RouterLinkStubDirective));
        links = linkDes
            .map((de: any) => de.injector
                .get(RouterLinkStubDirective) as RouterLinkStubDirective);
        landingPageLink = links[0].linkParams;
        profileLink = links[1].linkParams;
        aboutLink = links[2].linkParams;
        findLink = links[3].linkParams;
        addLink = links[4].linkParams;
        registerLink = links[5].linkParams;
    });

    it('can get RouterLinks from template', () => {
        expect(links.length).toBe(6, 'should have 6 links');
        expect(landingPageLink[0])
            .toEqual('/', '1st link should go to landing page');
        expect(profileLink[0])
            .toEqual('/profile', '2nd link should go to profile');
        expect(aboutLink[0])
            .toEqual('/about', '3rd link should go to about');
        expect(findLink[0])
            .toEqual('/find', '4th link should go to find');
        expect(addLink[0])
            .toEqual('/add', '5th link should go to add');
        expect(registerLink[0])
            .toEqual('/register', '6th link should go to register');
    });

    it('can click profile link in template', () => {
        const landingPageLinkDe = linkDes[0];
        const profileLinkDe = linkDes[1];
        const aboutLinkDe = linkDes[2];
        const findLinkDe = linkDes[3];
        const addLinkDe = linkDes[4];
        const registerLinkDe = linkDes[5];
        const landingPageLinkFull = links[0];
        const profileLinkFull = links[1];
        const aboutLinkFull = links[2];
        const findLinkFull = links[3];
        const addLinkFull = links[4];
        const registerLinkFull = links[5];

        navFixture.detectChanges();
        expect(profileLinkFull.navigatedTo)
            .toBeNull('link should not have navigated yet');
        profileLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
        landingPageLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
        aboutLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
        registerLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
        findLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });
        addLinkDe.triggerEventHandler('click', { button: 0 });

        navFixture.detectChanges();
        expect(landingPageLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/');
        expect(profileLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/profile');
        expect(aboutLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/about');
        expect(findLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/find');
        expect(addLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/add');
        expect(registerLinkFull.navigatedTo).toBe('/register');
    });
});
```

stub for test:

```
import 'zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/sync-test.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/proxy.js';
import 'zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js';

import {
   EventEmitter,
   Output,
   trigger,
   state,
   style,
   transition,
   animate,
   Directive,
   Input
} from '@angular/core';

import {
   ComponentFixture,
   TestBed,
   async,
   fakeAsync
} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
   BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
   platformBrowserDynamicTesting
} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
   DebugElement,
   Component,
   ViewChild,
   Pipe,
   PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NavbarComponent } from './shared/subcomponents/navbar.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { click } from './test/utilities.spec';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms'

@Directive({
  selector: '[routerLink]',
  host: {
    '(click)': 'onClick()'
  }
})
export class RouterLinkStubDirective {
  @Input('routerLink') linkParams: any;
  navigatedTo: any = null;

  onClick() {
    this.navigatedTo = this.linkParams[0];
  }
}
```

app.routes.ts:

```
import { Routes }  from '@angular/router';
import { LandingPageComponent } from './landing-page/landing-page.component';
import { FindPageComponent } from './find-page/find-page.component';
import { AddPageComponent } from './add-page/add-page.component';
import { RegisterPageComponent } from './register-page/register-page.component';
import { AboutPageComponent } from './about-page/about-page.component';
import { ProfilePageComponent } from './profile-page/profile-page.component';

export const routerConfig: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LandingPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'find',
    component: FindPageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'add',
    component: AddPageComponent
  },
    {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterPageComponent
  },
    {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutPageComponent
  },
    {
    path: 'profile',
    component: ProfilePageComponent
  }
];
```

navbar.component.html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-fixed-top text-uppercase">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <button     class="navbar-toggler hidden-md-up pull-xs-right" 
                    type="button" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    data-target="#nav-content">
                    &#9776;
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" [routerLink]="['/']" 
        routerLinkActive="active">vepo</a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-sm" id="nav-content">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/profile']" 
                    routerLinkActive="active">profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/about']" 
                    routerLinkActive="active">about</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/find']" 
                    routerLinkActive="active">find</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/add']" 
                    routerLinkActive="active">add</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <button type="button" class="as-text nav-link 
                    text-uppercase" (click)="openModal()">
                        login
                    </button>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link signup" [routerLink]="['/register']" 
                    routerLinkActive="active">sign up free</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<login #modal></login>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605119/

Comment: Note:RouterTestingModule and {provide: Router , useClass: RouterStub} won't work together.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. It was caused by a call to `router.navigate` inside the `ngOnInit` method of a component. The test was trying to create the component, but inside `ngOnInit` it was attempting to navigate away from the component (because certain conditions were not met).

In my case, I am importing the `RouterTestingModule` as part of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`. So to fix this I simply registered a route with `RouterTestingModule`. For example, suppose your navigation call looks like `router.navigate(['example'])` and it resolves to `ExampleComponent`. You can set up the test as follows:

```
RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
    { path: 'example', component: ExampleComponent}
])
```

Doing the above allowed my tests to run without issuing `Cannot match any routes` errors.

For what it's worth, I think a better way would be to stub the router and just confirm that appropriate calls to `navigate` are made.

Comment: Does this declaration to be included inside `beforeEach` ?

Comment: @forgottofly Yes, you place it in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule({ imports: [...] })` property

Comment: An alternative is to spyOn route.navigate in the beforeEach `spyOn(router, 'navigate').and.callFake(() => { });` and just call a fake. You can still test that navigate was called correctly using the spy `expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)`

Answer (score 19):

To expand on spoida's answer a little, I ended up using a stubbed router:

```
class RouterStub {
    url = '';
    navigate(commands: any[], extras?: any) { }
}
```

And then in your providers for your test:

```
providers: [
    { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }
    // ... other providers
]
```

This resulted in my unit test still passing and removed the console error I was seeing.