# How to configure a router in angular test case

Tags: angular, jasmine, router

In my angular 4 app, I am writing a test case for a method which navigates to a different route.
In my test case I am importing RouterTestingModule.withRoutes and passing the route.

```
const testRoutes: Routes = [ { path: 'sampleApp', component: SampleComponent}];
 imports: [RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(testRoutes)]
```

This doesn't seem to work I still get the error,

angular jasmine  ERROR: 'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot match any routes. URL Segment ...

How can I resolve this.

Comment: change `path: 'sampleApp'` to `path: ''`

Comment: @Xesenix, it doesn't work

Comment: If you stub the router like said in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41083089/unhandled-promise-rejection-cannot-match-any-routes is working for me