# Angular2 setting default route

Tags: angular, typescript

Am setting my routing in the module and i would like to set default route but it fails

This is the routing module

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, useAsDefault:true }, //returns an error
 {
  path: 'dash',
  redirectTo:"dashboard"
},

{ path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
{ path: '',    redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'  },
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

The above returns an error of

```
LoginComponent; useAsD...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'
```

What could be wrong

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605119/angular2-router-angular-router-how-to-set-default-route

Comment: What's wrong ? u have nice and clearlly response of error ;) coz Router didnt have a `useAsDefault` property, check it: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Route-interface.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When using useAsDefault you need to have the parent route and the useAsDefault on the child route you want to appear first.
So, No need of useAsDefault, You can simply gives Login As Default Routes.And As I see there is no Imported component for Dashboard so,

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: "/login",
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'reset-password', component: ResetPasswordComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```