# How can I make a URL non-modifiable on Angular?

Tags: html, angular, web

Ok, so there's this project i'm working on where we have a particular page (lets say localhost:XXXX/notification-page) and we're looking for it to be the only URL where you can get there, whenever we change the url it sends you to the same exact page (the notification-page one).

I'm pretty new to Angular (been working with it for about three days from scratch), so... How could I fix that?

So far, my app-routing.module.ts document looks like this:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: See redirectTo https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 router (@angular/router), how to set default route?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37605119/angular2-router-angular-router-how-to-set-default-route)

Comment: you can do a [redirect](https://angular.io/guide/router#setting-up-redirects), you can also set up 404.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to make only one route "localhost:XXXX/notification-page" for this you can make routing like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
       { path: '', redirectTo: '/notification-page', pathMatch: 'full'}
       { path: '**', redirectTo: '/notification-page', pathMatch: 'full' },
];
```